# Will Solaris 9 drivers work on Solaris 10?

Tags: solaris, drivers

I'm going to try this anyway right now, but since it's a decent question I thought I should throw it on Server Fault. I'd like a reason why they shouldn't work since the Kernel is so old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will likely work. Solaris is providing a stable API/ABI for device drivers developers so there is no need to recompile them should a new kernel release is out.